# Pass list of selected SObject records to Remoteaction method

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller, remote-action

I have below code where I am trying to pass a List of Accounts to Remoteaction method from a VF Page.

I am able to pass one as below, but can't figure out for a list of Accounts. Can someone please help?

**Script on Apex Page function**

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.VueDataTableExampleController_test.addToTerritory}', JSON.stringify(account),
                            function (result, event) {
                                if (event.status) {
                                    console.log('event.status', event.status);
                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                                    console.log('exception');
                                } else {
                                    console.log(event.type);
                                }
                            }, {
                                escape: true
                            }
                        );
```

**Apex controller**

```
  @RemoteAction
    public static void addToTerritory(String accountToUpdate) {
        Account updatedAccount = (Account)JSON.deserialize(accountToUpdate, Account.class);
       // update updatedAccount;
        if(vAddToTerrMessage == 'AlignementBlock')
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,GAS_Add_To_Terr_Block_Message));
          //  return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is this `account` ? javascript object? and FYI: You can't add page message from remote Action method

Comment: ok. No this account is salesforce standard object. I need to pass List<Account> to this remote method from page. I am able to pass one Account but not List. Can you please help?

Comment: ohh you can't pass the list<Account> directly. you have to use some workaround logic. like use apex:repeat to iterate over the list<Account> and then convert each account into javascript variable and they together pass all the records to remove action.

Comment: Can you please help me here?